# RAILS 4 After editing and updating, the id of posts is passed as user why?

Tags: redirect, ruby-on-rails-4, updates

I have a user model that has_many posts, but I have few issues when a user updates a post. When a first user (user id:1) updates a post, (say post id:13), upon redirect, the page tries to redirect to user id:13. Does anyone know why this is? Here are my lines of code.. Thanks in advance.

posts_controller.rb
.
.
.

```
  def update
    @post = current_user.posts.find(params[:id])
    if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
      redirect_to user_path, notice: "Successfully updated!"
    else
      render action: "edit"
    end
  end
```

users_controller.rb
.
.
.

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @posts = @user.posts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
redirect_to **user_path**, notice: "Successfully updated!"
```

You are redirecting to the user_path. You want to redirect to the post_path. Unless what you want is directing to the user_path. Then, you need to pass it the user id: `user_path(current_user.id)`